# Cisco Pix 501 (and probably 506e) PDM web access and Java errors

Tags: cisco, java, cisco-pix

Are there any nice options for using the PDM on an old Cisco Pix 501 or 506e with modern computers/browsers? I have an old 501 at a remote site and only have https access to it from my location. I can make the changes via command line, but due to the restricted access, need to use the web interface. Unfortunately, the Java console gives an ugly error before the PDM starts. I've tried this with all of the systems and browsers that I have on hand.

Here's the output from a Windows XP workstation:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Thu, 12 May 2011 21:34:02 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 30
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: https://xxx.xxx.yyy.yyy/pdm.html
```

In general, are there any tricks for dealing with these non-upgradeable Cisco devices? At least the 515e units and above could take the ASA software. Is the resolution just to keep an old PC or Java instance available for the one-off old firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to spin up a VM with the right JVM installed. IIRC you can't upgrade past 1.5.20 or so or you get that error.

Comment: I'll do so. I couldn't remember what the cutoff was.

Answer (score 0):

I rolled-back to Java 6 update 7 on an XP VM, and the PDM came right up.